# Custom fields on custom post type archive

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I've run into the following problem.

I've made 2 custom post types, each, ofcourse, containing posts.

But now I've run into a situation where I would need to add a custom field at the top of the archive page.

Since I don't have a page I can access on the admin side, I can't fill these custom fields.

Should I switch to a page, or is there a other way?

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If you declare so when you register your custom post types, they have custom fields the same as the normal Post type. Do you mean that when you edit a post from one of your custom types, you are unable to see the custom fields box?

Comment: No, the problem is this. I've got a custom post type which outputs it's posts into the following template file: archive-"post-type".php   I want to use a custom post type to create a intro text explaining what all these posts are about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May way of doing this is to create a page and put the content in there then use the following code at the top of your archive"post-type".php to display it.

```
$myposts = get_posts( array('post_type'=>'page','numberposts' => 1,'include' => 45) );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post); ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('grid_5'); ?>>
                <header class="entry-header">
                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .entry-header -->
                <div class="entry-content">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-content -->
            </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
         <?php endforeach; // end of the loop. ?>
```

All you need to do is replace the 'include' => 45 with your own page id.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :(